# How to resolve compile error : "AttValue: " or ' expected" in xcode

Tags: swift

I have renamed my project and after doing all the stuff and resolving all the errors , I face the following error in "**TakeEditCell.xib**":

```
 Line 15: AttValue: " or ' expected
 Line 15: attributes construct error
 Line 15: Couldn't find end of Start Tag tableViewCell
```

**Here is the code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="12120" systemVersion="16E195" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="ipad9_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="12088"/>
        <capability name="Constraints to layout margins" minToolsVersion="6.0"/>
        <capability name="Constraints with non-1.0 multipliers" minToolsVersion="5.1"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" id="wS8-vg-jwz" customClass="TakeEditCell" customModule=“ProjXXX” customModuleProvider="target">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="360"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="wS8-vg-jwz" id="Utt-1e-lcR">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="359.5"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                <subviews>
                    <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="BmU-14-LCQ">
                        <rect key="frame" x="16" y="24" width="150" height="144"/>
                    </imageView>
                    <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="qlG-3t-cI6">
                        <rect key="frame" x="209" y="24" width="150" height="144"/>
                    </imageView>
                    <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="gho-rc-34o">
                        <rect key="frame" x="16" y="184" width="150" height="143.5"/>
                    </imageView>
                    <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="bHt-0J-ApW">
                        <rect key="frame" x="209" y="184" width="150" height="143.5"/>
                    </imageView>
                </subviews>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint firstItem="bHt-0J-ApW" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="BmU-14-LCQ" secondAttribute="width" id="3aA-8U-9wy"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="BmU-14-LCQ" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="Utt-1e-lcR" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="4:10" id="6OS-Y2-kG2"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="BmU-14-LCQ" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Utt-1e-lcR" secondAttribute="topMargin" constant="16" id="BWB-xz-0p1"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="gho-rc-34o" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="BmU-14-LCQ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="16" id="Ca2-eW-pZc"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="bHt-0J-ApW" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="BmU-14-LCQ" secondAttribute="height" id="HHb-gN-yip"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="qlG-3t-cI6" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="BmU-14-LCQ" secondAttribute="width" id="I9l-S5-Ara"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="gho-rc-34o" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="BmU-14-LCQ" secondAttribute="height" id="NR0-h1-OdF"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="bHt-0J-ApW" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="qlG-3t-cI6" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="16" id="Sjs-Eo-kXO"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="qlG-3t-cI6" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Utt-1e-lcR" secondAttribute="topMargin" constant="16" id="T6v-sn-eyA"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="BmU-14-LCQ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Utt-1e-lcR" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" constant="8" id="aDx-cC-L9V"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="bHt-0J-ApW" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="htv-Ey-z5r"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="gho-rc-34o" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="BmU-14-LCQ" secondAttribute="width" id="lfP-06-sJF"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="qlG-3t-cI6" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="BmU-14-LCQ" secondAttribute="height" id="qla-mw-D06"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="qlG-3t-cI6" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="t5U-t8-dw2"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="gho-rc-34o" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Utt-1e-lcR" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" constant="8" id="uFq-CZ-EZ1"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="BmU-14-LCQ" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="Utt-1e-lcR" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="4:10" id="zXA-DD-WpX"/>
                </constraints>
            </tableViewCellContentView>
            <connections>
                <outlet property="imageView1" destination="BmU-14-LCQ" id="3TE-4D-xyQ"/>
                <outlet property="imageView2" destination="qlG-3t-cI6" id="HUi-SF-bI6"/>
                <outlet property="imageView3" destination="gho-rc-34o" id="x98-iX-GIR"/>
                <outlet property="imageView4" destination="bHt-0J-ApW" id="YWl-Rb-vJT"/>
            </connections>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-73.5" y="4"/>
        </tableViewCell>
    </objects>
</document>
```

It seems that **tableViewCell** has been **closed** properly.

I even tried to *replace* "**TakeEditCell**.xib" file with the ***original*** one from *backup* but it didn't help, I also read other posts but none of them were helpful.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is this part having a different double quote compared to other part. `customModule=“ProjXXX”` Change it and it will work.

Comment: @Adev, Thanks a lot you are absolutely right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have *smart quotes* in your .xib file there on line 15:

Change:

```
<tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" id="wS8-vg-jwz" customClass="TakeEditCell" customModule=“ProjXXX” customModuleProvider="target">
```

to:

```
<tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" id="wS8-vg-jwz" customClass="TakeEditCell" customModule="ProjXXX" customModuleProvider="target">
```

That probably happened when you manually edited your .xib file using TextEdit or some other non-IDE app.

When editing a .xib file's guts outside of Xcode's Interface Builder functionality, you can "open as source code" in Xcode by clicking on the .xib icon in the left side of the Xcode window (where files and folders live) while holding down the control key to bring up a contextual menu.